# Ivy - include dependencies while working in IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, dependency-management, ivy

I integrated Apache Ivy into my build so that I can add dependencies and they are automatically included in my built web app.

This works fine and the appropriate `jar`'s are placed in the 
`build/web/WEB-INF/lib` folder when I build my web app.

However, when working in my IDE (Netbeans), it is unaware of the imported libraries (they are only placed in the `build` folder once I build the web app). So it is filled with a bunch of errors since it doesn't recognize any code involving the dependencies imported by Ivy.

This is my ivy.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="some.org" module="some.mod"/>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency org="com.github.dfabulich" name="sitemapgen4j" rev="1.0.6"/>
        </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Is there a way to make Netbeans aware of dependencies imported by Ivy?

Or, do I have to run a "build" at least once and then simply manually include the desired libraries (ie: right clicking `libraries` -> clicking `add jar/folder`) by referencing the appropriate jars in the `build` folder?

I would think Ivy/Netbeans could automate this so that I don't have to manually include the jars that are included in the dependencies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqIvy

But i recommend you to use [gradle](https://gradle.org/) as build and dependency manager instead of ant.

Comment: I had a look at that link but it doesn't discuss what I'm asking.